# standardization/normalization for 1D clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have two input variables `revenue` and `age`. Am trying to find different bins within that variables.

For ex: I have `revenue` and `age`.

I see that my revenue data is skewly distributed and regular methods like quantiles, binning etc cannot be applied due to skewness (and gives misleading results).

Is it a good practice to scale/normalize the 1d data before we apply techniques like `jenks natural breaks`??

Or we should standardize/nornalize only for k-means multivariate clustering algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Jenks natural breaks optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) is 1D k-means, and scaling and shifting is done typically for bringing different features into one scale.  If there is only one feature, shifting and scaling won't change the resulting clusters if same (shifted and scaled as well) random initialization is used. But, you could apply other transformations, such as log transformation, to battle with skew and see if it helps with your cluster assignments.

Comment: nice. Then can I check whether it is incorrect to do multiple 1d clustering/1d-kmeans instead of single multivariate clustering? you can find more info here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576980/multiple-univariate-clustering-vs-single-multivariate-clustering

Comment: Additionally, is it good to apply a stack of transformers? Like 1st apply log transformation, on top of that I apply sqrt transformation, later I apply box transformation etc? Can I keep applying until I remove skewness to the best way possible?

Comment: You can apply transformations any way/order you like. Note though that after log transformation, there maybe negative values, and sqrt may not be appropriate. Checking 1d vs nd clustering is a post-analysis and decoupled from what you do here.

Comment: Understand. yes, I meant it would be helpful if I could have your views on 1d vs nd clustering post that I linked.